# htaccess redirect url into subfolder and hide subfolder in url, for only 1 page

Tags: .htaccess, hide, subdirectory

.htaccess problem:

I want domain.com/page5 to bring up,

domain.com/folder/page5

but still show domain.com/page5 as the url.

Let this only work for this exact page, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteRule ^page5$ /folder/page5 [NC,L]
```